# How do I achieve the image this with the code that I have?? I wanna use onChange and something like onMouseChange

Tags: javascript, html

I want my code to function like the image that I am pasted:

[image]

- When a user selects a destination the big picture(main image) changes to that corresponding destination but the thumbnails images also change with it, showing 6 other images that accompany the destination that the user chose. Also when you hover over a thumbnail it shows up in the big image
  (main image container).
- The problem with my code now is NOT that the images don't change when I click on a different select option BUT that the big image doesn't appear and also when I hover over a thumbnail the big image doesn't change to what I am hovering over.
- I didn't include as many images as the example but I looking to achieve the same overall functionality. I don't really care about how it looks visually.

Here is the code:

```html
<form id="form">
  <div>
    <div>
      <select id="s1" onchange="changePictures()">
        <option value="Africa">Africa</option>
        <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
        <option value="London">London</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<div id="thumbnailsContainer">
  <div id="thumb1" class="thumbnail">
    <img src="images/africa1.jpg" width="50" height="60" />
  </div>
  <div id="thumb2" class="thumbnail">
    <img src="images/africa2.jpg" width="50" height="60" />
  </div>
    <div id="thumb3" class="thumbnail">
  <img src="images/africa3.jpg" width="50" height="60" />
    </div>
  <div id="thumb4" class="thumbnail">
    <img src="images/africa4.jpg" width="50" height="60" />
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
const africaImages = [
    { src: "images/africa1.jpg" },
    { src: "images/africa2.jpg" },
    { src: "images/africa3.jpg" },
    { src: "images/africa4.jpg" },
];
const japanImages = [
    { src: "images/japan2.jpg" },
    { src: "images/japan3.jpg" },
    { src: "images/japan4.jpg" },
    { src: "images/japan6.jpg" },
];
const londonImages = [
    { src: "images/london1.jpg" },
    { src: "images/london2.jpg" },
    { src: "images/london3.jpg" },
    { src: "images/london4.jpg" },
];
```

```js
function changePictures() {
    const selectedOption = document.getElementById("s1").value;
    currentOption = selectedOption;

    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        document
          .getElementById(`thumb${i + 1}`)
          .getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = thumbnails[selectedOption][i].src;
    }

    document.getElementsByName("bp")[0].src = thumbnails[selectedOption][0].src;
}
```

Comment: I tried to make the objects more readable but it doesn't let me. Sorry about that.

Comment: Please add your event to the question

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: You don't have `changePictures()` in your js code.

Comment: Ohh sorry about that. I just added it but again it's not formatting for some reason.

Comment: See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on how to format your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I combined `africaImages`, `japanImages`, `londonImages` to `images`.

Select them by `images[select.value]`.

Recreate thumbnails from `images[select.value]` and add `mouseenter` on them.

```js
const images = {
  Africa: [{
    src: "images/africa1.jpg"
  }, {
    src: "images/africa2.jpg"
  }, {
    src: "images/africa3.jpg"
  }, {
    src: "images/africa4.jpg"
  }],
  Japan: [{
    src: "images/japan2.jpg"
  }, {
    src: "images/japan3.jpg"
  }, {
    src: "images/japan4.jpg"
  }, {
    src: "images/japan6.jpg"
  }],
  London: [{
    src: "images/london1.jpg"
  }, {
    src: "images/london2.jpg"
  }, {
    src: "images/london3.jpg"
  }, {
    src: "images/london4.jpg"
  }],
};
const container = document.getElementById("thumbnailsContainer");
const select = document.getElementById("s1");
const main = document.getElementById("main");
const thumbs = document.getElementsByClassName("thumbnail");
const changePictures = () => {
  container.innerHTML = images[select.value].map((img) => `<div class="thumbnail"><img src="${img.src}" width="50" height="60" /></div>`).join("");
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(thumbs, (d) => d.addEventListener("mouseenter", changeMain));
};
const changeMain = (e) => {
  main.innerHTML = `<img src="${e.target.children[0].src}">`;
};
changePictures();
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <div>
    <div>
      <select id="s1" onchange="changePictures()">
        <option value="Africa">Africa</option>
        <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
        <option value="London">London</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<div id="thumbnailsContainer"></div>
<div id="main"><img src=""></div>
```

Comment: Ahh I see, there we go. I have a random question why did you include the script in the head? Originally I put it in the body, but I'm not 100% sure what the difference is.

Comment: To make it looks tidy. I add `defer` on script so it will execute after the page loaded. If not use `defer`, the script must put after the content or the js code (ex: `getElement...`) can't get anything.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to add `<script>` or `<link>` in SO snippet, I just forgot to delete it.